# How to automatically look up values on another worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a spreadsheet for delivering different items. "page 1" will be the delivery form, "page 2" is the list of item numbers and their individual costs. There are over 200 items and growing.

On "page 1", I would like to input the item # in column A and have the cost self-populate column B (cost information is on "page 2").  I want to do this in an automated way with a formula rather than having to manually look up each individual cost.

I've been trying IF functions but don't know how to do them with this quantity of items.  I've also looked at VLOOKUP, but don't understand how to use it to reference data on another sheet.

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Comment: I've been trying "if" functions but dont know how to do them with the number of item numbers..

Comment: You mean you don't want to manually look up each record?  Check out VLOOKUP.  You would create one formula to automatically look up the cost and then populate that as much as needed.

Comment: How does that work when I'm trying get the prices from a different page?

Comment: What do you mean? It works the same as if you're trying to get prices on the same page, except with a sheet reference.  What have you tried? What's your formula?

Comment: this is the formula I just tried but its not working, just getting  #ref!  ..               =VLOOKUP(A2,A2:A55,'page 2'!B2:B81, FALSE)

Comment: `=Vlookup(A2,'page 2'!$A$2:$B$51,2,FALSE)` should do it. Put this in Page 1, `B2` and drag down.

Comment: BruceWayne  That did it.. I knew I was doing something wrong in the formula.. Thank you